# How to use BigQuery UNNEST in order to see every single struct and its values in a single and not multiple rows?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

This query gives the rows as a result in which every single row contains key and value from the struct. However I want that rows which are part of one struct to be in a single and not multiple rows.

`` SELECT event_date, event_name, param.key as key, param.value.string_value as value from `project_name.dataset_name.table_name` cross join UNNEST(event_params) as param where event_name = 'a' and (param.key = 'b' or param.key = 'c') and 
CASE
  WHEN key = 'b' THEN CAST(param.value.string_value AS FLOAT64) > 5 else CAST(param.value.string_value AS FLOAT64) > 0 
END ``

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your question really does not make sense.  A repeated record *is* in one row -- it is just repeated so BigQuery displays it on multiple rows for presentation purposes.

Comment: So programitically it understands as one row? Just shows multiple for presentation?

Comment: . . Yes, that is how repeated fields are handled.